# How do I change the path for generated files for the generator-angular in yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

## My question:

From the readme on https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

`yo angular:controller user`

Produces

`app/scripts/controllers/user.js`

How do I make it produce

`app/js/controllers/user.js`

## What I've looked at:

I don't think I can configure the path since the source shows that the path is hard codded:

```
Generator.prototype.createControllerFiles = function createControllerFiles() {
  this.appTemplate('controller', 'scripts/controllers/' + this.name);
  this.testTemplate('spec/controller', 'controllers/' + this.name);
  this.addScriptToIndex('controllers/' + this.name);
};
```

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/controller/index.js#L22

I've considered forking the project and changing the code, but that feels dirty. 
I'm hoping that there is a configuration i can change, but there is no github wiki, so I can't exactly RTM to find the configuration options. I tried looking in https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/script-base.js but that wasn't very helpful either.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no fix for this right now.

But the good news is that the team is working on a solution for this. See [this Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/distilledhype/status/382179393525014528).

Comment: good to see. I'm trying to use it in conjunction with linemanjs and ended up breaking a bunch of stuff in my project T.T

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine, a configuration for those paths is really important in order to add an Angular App to any site really.

Comment: been looking into this myself. I found this page on generator-angular https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commit/220a9436fa660f36ec6560cf38bdf62b7440c0e1 "allow movement of app and test folder via component.json " , so it looks as though this behaviour was deprecated at some point?