# How to change the folder where yeoman generator-angular create test files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using Yeoman/Grunt/Bower/Jasmim/Karma and I would like to know how can I change the folder where [Yeoman generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) generates the test files.

I've changed the appPath property of my bower.json to /src/main/resources/scripts, so when I run the command **yo angular:controller myController**, a controller is generated under this folder. It is ok, however, the test file, for this controller, is generated under a folder called test on project root. I would like to have it created on /src/tests/resources/scripts is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue trying to change the controller folder for some without the scripts part.
I found this answer from 2013 but for the moment I don't find any configuration for that.
Related twitter question https://twitter.com/kahliltweets/status/382179393525014528
and Stackoverflow question [How do I change the path for generated files for the generator-angular in yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703293/how-do-i-change-the-path-for-generated-files-for-the-generator-angular-in-yeoman)

Harcoded line https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/script-base.js#L129

If you want you can change this folder on your machine or fork and fix this issue :D.

Hope this "answer" helps you and good luck!